# No MAC address di iMX51_bbg froyo 2.2 Epad 8'

Tags: internet

I've bought an iMX51_bbg Froyo 2.2 Epad 8', but I cannot find the MAC address. Can you help me with that?

Is there any USB Modem compatible with this Android device? I've tried many and can't get them to work!  The phone works properly with WiFi, but it's annoying if I have to go to free WiFi place if I just want to surf.

Comment: I don't know of any Android device that will work with an external modem.  Your question isn't very clear, for example you say WiFi works properly but it sounds like it's not working.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the MAC address in your Settings.

`Menu | Settings | About phone | Status | Wi-Fi MAC address`

Comment: thanks ive found in advance wifi setting... sorry me newbie...